# Plotly "No DOM element with id 'dept-sunburst' exists on the page"

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

So basically I am receiving this error: "No DOM element with id 'dept-sunburst' exists on the page". I am using the Plotly.js library and "dept-sunburst" is the id of the canvas I want to put my graph in.

The reason this issue is here is because I navigate to a new page to show the data, which I know because it works when I don't change the page. I think it is because of one of two reasons, either Plotly doesn't load the new page's DOM or the element doesn't load by the time the graph is being created. I don't have a solution to either of these.

```
//getting the data
$.ajax({
    url: 'send',
    method: 'post'
}).done((data) => {
    window.location = window.location.href + "results.html";
    //creates the graph
    calculate_dept_sunburst(data);
});
```

Comment: I don't think you can access the current context (specifically the DOM and data object) after assigning a new value to `window.location`. If you need to navigate to a new page to show the results then you must find another solution to pass the data.

Comment: However, if you're executing an AJAX request to retrieve the data why are you navigating away from the page? You could display the graph in the current page.